# Terraform Azure provider - can OS disk be encrypted only with azurerm_linux_virtual_machine?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

If so, what about other machines OS?
I can only see the documentation of disk encryption inside the azurerm_linux_virtual_machine resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, Disk encryption also supports Windows Azure VM.

You could see an `os_disk` block supports the following:

[image]

The `disk_encryption_set_id`is used to encrypt this OS Disk from [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/windows_virtual_machine.html#os_disk)

Then to encrypt the OS disk, you will create [azurerm_disk_encryption_set](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/disk_encryption_set.html) resource and reference it in the Azure VM OS disk like this:

```
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    
    disk_encryption_set_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.id   #use for disk encryption
  }
```